# Where should I ask on the SE community about a non-programming question related to google earth?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I want to ask something about [Google Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Earth) that is not related to development of any kind. Where should I ask in the SE community?

Comment: Welcomo to [meta.se]. What do you want to ask about Google Earth?

Comment: Take a look to the results of https://stackexchange.com/search?q=google-earth it might give you an idea of what sites have questions that mentions "google earth".

Comment: I want to ask if you can access high resolution satelite pictures

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add that and the Google Earth version  (web, mobile, desktop) and the name and version of the operative system that you are using direclty into the question body.

Answer (score 2):

Our "Geographic Information Systems" site contains:

- 806 questions tagged ["Google Earth"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth)
- 853 questions tagged ["Google Earth Engine Javascript API"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine-javascript-api)
- and 4654 questions tagged ["Goggle Earth Engine"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine)
- for a total of 5577 search results for ["Google Earth"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=Google+Earth).

Another site may be: "Earth Science" where a search for "Google Earth" returns results for 140 questions about for ["remote sensing"](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=Google+Earth) and other related tags.

Our "Space Stack Exchange" site has:

- 162 search results for ["Google Earth"](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=Google+Earth)

Our "Web Applications" site has:

- 19 questions tagged ["Google Earth"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth) (suggested by @[V2Blast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/335251/v2blast) in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383943/where-should-i-ask-on-the-se-community-about-a-non-programming-question-related/383946?noredirect=1#comment1280784_383946)).

Even our "Salesforce" (Customer Relations Management) software site has [3 questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=Google+Earth+) and our "Tex" site has [20 questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Google+Earth+) about Google Earth; so you need to post where your question can be best answered.

Comment: [Web Applications also has a `google-earth` tag with 19 questions.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are interested in using an **application that can be accessed through a web browser**, I would suggest **[webapps.stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com)**.

They already have some questions tagged [`google-earth`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth).

As always, please check the [community guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You commented that:

> I want to ask if you can access high resolution satelite pictures

I suspect that this is a question that only Google can answer because if it is satellite images you see on Google Earth then it will need knowledge of their data licensing.

The GIS Stack Exchange has a Custom Close Reason which I suspect would lead to your question being quickly closed there:

> Questions that relate to the business of vendors and product teams,
> such as **licensing**, **pricing**, **release dates**, submission of
> **bug reports** and **enhancement requests**, etc, are off-topic here and should be directed instead to the official software support team.